# tcgetpgrp returns 0 -- implications?

Tags: c, linux, manpage, pty

### Context:

I'm working on an application that needs to determine whether the
pseudo-terminal opened by a process is its controlling terminal. I'm trying to
use the `tcgetpgrp()` libc/system call to achieve this.

### Observations:

1) I noticed that `tcgetpgrp()` returns 0 for the master pseudo-terminal in the
   simple application below. I'm running Glibc 2.25 on Linux 4.10.3.

```
int main()
{
  int master_fd = open("/dev/ptmx", O_RDWR);
  grantpt(master_fd);
  unlockpt(master_fd);
  char *slave_pty = ptsname(master_fd);
  int slave_fd = open(slave_pty, O_RDWR);
  struct termios term;
  tcgetattr(slave_fd, &term);
  term.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ICANON | IEXTEN | ISIG);
  tcsetattr(slave_fd, TCSANOW, &term);
  if (fork()) {
    // parent
    close(slave_fd);
    while (1) {
      pid_t pgrp = tcgetpgrp(master_fd);
      // tcgetpgrp on master_fd returns 0
      printf("tcgetpgrp returned: %d\n", pgrp);
      sleep(1);
    }
  } else {
    // child
    close(master_fd);
    while (1) {
      pid_t pgrp = tcgetpgrp(slave_fd);
      // tcgetpgrp on slave_fd returns -1
      printf("tcgetpgrp returned: %d\n", pgrp);
      sleep(1);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

2) The Linux man page for `tcgetpgrp()` says that:

> When  fd  refers  to the controlling terminal of the calling
>   process, the function tcgetpgrp() will return the foreground process
>   group ID of that terminal if there is one, and some value larger
>   than 1 that is not presently a process group ID otherwise.  When
>   fd does not refer to the controlling terminal of the calling
>   process, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately.

3) The POSIX man page for `tcgetpgrp()` says that:

> Upon  successful  completion,  tcgetpgrp()  shall  return  the
>   value of the process group ID of the foreground process associated
>   with the terminal. Otherwise, −1 shall be returned and errno set
>   to indicate the error.

4) Looking through the libc source, I found that the only thing the `tcgetpgrp()` wrapper does
is call into the kernel using `ioctl(TIOCGPGRP)` and forward the return value
to the caller.

### Questions:

- Unless I'm misinterpreting it, the Linux man seems to be ambiguous about
  what happens when the fd passed to tcgetpgrp is not the controlling terminal
  of the calling process. While the first sentence seems to be saying that a
  value > 1 will be returned, the second sentence says that -1 will be
  returned.
- When the man page says a value > 1 will be returned that is not a process
  group, does it mean that I have to go through the list of all the process
  groups in the system to figure out if the return value refers to a valid
  process group?
- What is the meaning of a return value of 0? Is that a valid process group?
- Is there something that I'm missing in my program?

I'm still trying to trace it through the kernel sources ... but does
anyone know the history behind this?

(My understanding is that the master is typically not supposed to be a controlling terminal, but the system call behavior and the explanation on the man page still appear to be weird.)

Thanks.